# Shift non empty cell values to closest empty cells to the left

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a lot of rows formatted like this:

```
COLS : A | B | C | D | E
  01 : 1 |   | 8 | 3 |
  02 :   | 3 | 2 | 4 | 7
  03 : 9 |   | 5 |   | 6
```

How can I shift the values to the left so I don't have empty cells? Goal is:

```
COLS : A | B | C | D | E
  01 : 1 | 8 | 3 |   |
  02 : 3 | 2 | 4 | 7 |
  03 : 9 | 5 | 6 |   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you only have a single cell selected.

1. Press F5
2. Click the "Special..." button
3. Select "Blanks" and click OK
4. Right click and select "Delete..."
5. Select the "Shift cells left" option and press OK

I'm using 2010, so it might be a little different for 2013, but I'm hoping that it's more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub DataCompactor()
    Dim iRows As Long, iCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Range

    iRows = 3
    iCols = 5

    For i = 1 To iRows
        For j = iCols To 1 Step -1
            Set r = Cells(i, j)
            If r.Value = "" Then r.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

*If the cells are truly empty, you can use `SpecialCells` and avoid the loops.*

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

You must change the ***3*** and ***5*** to match your actual data structure.

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: How do I use that? Sorry.. I'm new at this.. Also this is an example.. I have around 4k rows

Comment: @Onilol  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Onilol  Don't forget to fix `iRows` and `iCols`

Answer (score 0):

If the request is move the cells to the left instead of deleting the cells (because one needs to keep the rest of the columns fixed outside the range), what can be done?

Basically in the original example, it means that any content starting from column I want them as they are without moving to the left, what should one do?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your post appears to be a question instead of an answer.  Your question will get the appropriate attention if you post it as a new question. You will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the Stack Overflow [tour] and review site guidelines on [ask] and [answer].  If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.